# python recognize string as data already in bites, or force a bypass to encode and convert object

Tags: python, hex

In python I have a string of hex values 'e65814e4382759f85550029e723dc7e7' that I want to encode to bytes, the problem is that if I use

```
b'string'
```

or

```
bytes(string, 'ascii')
```

it encodes the value as if it were a string  into bytes, however they're not, it's already a set of 16 hexadecimal pairs.

So how do I get python to recognize what I wrote as data already in bites, or force a bypass to encode and convert object "as is" in a sence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `binascii` module:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> hexstr = 'e65814e4382759f85550029e723dc7e7'
>>> binascii.unhexlify(hexstr)
b"\xe6X\x14\xe48'Y\xf8UP\x02\x9er=\xc7\xe7"
```

And to prove to yourself...

```
>>> [f"{b:x}" for b in  binascii.unhexlify(hexstr)]
['e6', '58', '14', 'e4', '38', '27', '59', 'f8', '55', '50', '2', '9e', '72', '3d', 'c7', 'e7']
```